# Deed poll name changes alter egos

Tags: england-and-wales, name

If [deed polls](https://www.gov.uk/change-name-deed-poll) are a legal way to change your name in the UK, then what will prevent deed polls from being used to legally create alter egos for yourself, and you to enter into contracts with one of your own alter egos?

Comment: Wouldn't changing your name mean the old name is no longer valid and a contract with that would refer to the new name?

Comment: @JoeW the point of deed polls is that  it is just a piece of paper you’re writing yourself in which you announce your new name, so you only change your name to the people who you have announced your new name, all the other people who are not aware of your new name would still refer to you using the old name

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though. Are you suggesting that a deed poll allows you to have multiple legal names at the same time? Or are you saying that a deed poll is just asking people to call you something different?

Comment: @JoeW yes, as deed polls would allow you to have a passport, ID card, driver’s license and bank accounts issued in your new name, but only when you request to do so

Comment: Yes to having multiple legal names at the same time?

Comment: @JoeW if you know how to play the game, it would mean Multiple legal names at once

Answer (score 3):

A change of name is just that - it's a change; not the creation of an alter ego.

From [How to make your own deed poll](https://www.gov.uk/change-name-deed-poll/make-an-adult-deed-poll):

> Use the following wording:
>
> “I [old name] of [your address] **have given up** my name [old name] and have adopted **for all purposes** the name [new name].

And from the [Form LOC19 guidance document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/apply-to-change-your-name-forms-loc020-loc021-and-loc025):

> I ABSOLUTELY and entirely **renounce relinquish and abandon the use of my old name** and assume adopt and determine to take and use from the date of this Deed my new name in substitution for my old name.

Comment: The old name would always stick around somewhere, so you could imagine a scenario in which your new company using your new name could be acquiring your old company in which you used the old name

Answer (score 1):

As @Rick’s answer says, a Deed Poll involves formally renouncing the old name when taking the new so it does not create an alter-ego.

However, that just begs the question: is it legal to have and se an alter-ego?

In most cases, yes.

Your “name” is simply the words that are associated with you so that you and other people know that it’s you that’s being talked about when they are used. You can have as many as you like and any of the ones you have can be used in most private legal contexts like entering contracts.

The government usually insists that you use the name on your birth certificate (or deed poll) but if you enter a contract under a maiden name or a nickname, you will be bound to that contract.

You can never enter a contract with yourself, even if yourself has different names.

Comment: there’s absolutely nothing preventing you from entering into a contract with yourself: you can be hired as employee of your own company where you are the only director for example

Comment: @user1095332 that’s not a contract with yourself, that’s a contract between you and a seperate legal person, your company.

Comment: that’s just a point of view, another point of view is that the legal person is just a special purpose vehicle of yourself, therefore essentially entering into a contract with yourself

Comment: @user1095332 it’s not a point of view, it’s a legal fact

Comment: Then it would also be a legal fact that you can have a scenario in which your new company in the UK that accepts your new name from the deed poll  could be acquiring your old Company in another foreign country outside the UK that does not accept deed polls name changes at all and where you used the old name from the birth certificate

Comment: @user1095332 what?

Comment: You can have the new legal name accepted and the old name abandoned  in the UK, but that does not have to be the case in a foreign country outside the UK that does not accept deed poll name changes at all